# Send Push Notification To a Windows Phone 8.1 app Without submitting it to store

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, mpns, wns

I want to send to push notification to a windows phone 8.1 app that currently not submitted to store. is there a way for this situation?

I know that `MPNS` can send unauthenticated push notification (with some limits). but is there a way to send unauthenticated push notification through WNS (as I know cloud server must first authenticate  itself via `Package SID` and `Client Secret`)?

for the last question is this assumption is true?

windows phone 8 -> can only use MPNS

windows phone 8.1 Silverlight - > can use both MPNS and WNS

windows phone 8.1 Universal -> can use WNS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use push notifications before publishing by getting a packageSID and client secret to authenticate against WNS by just reserving a name for your app in the Store and then going to Services --> Push notifications. There's no way to use WNS unauthenticated but you don't need to submit your app to get that authentication working.

And yes, your assumptions are correct.